# Mail Merge from Multiple SQL Tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-word, mailmerge

> We have three tables TABLE1, TABLE2 and TABLE3.
>
> TABLE1 has primary key TABLE1_PK which is a foreign key for other two tables. We have a document in MS-Word, which fills the data from these three tables columns based on the TABLE1_PK.
>
> In MS-Word we found the mail merge option from the SQL Server but not with Multiple tables.

```
Is there any option to do mail merge from more than one SQL Tables?
```

> Note: we are using SQL server 2008 R2 and MS-word2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you make a view on your database accessing the three tables as necessary; then in word do your mail merge against the view?